# To show $\exists t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q=t^2$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $a,b,c\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=p/q$, $y=r/s$ be two rationals satisfying the equation $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$.

Prove,
$\exists t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that,
$q=t^2$, $s=t^3$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $q^3 s^2$

Comment: then, any hint? @ user44197

Comment: I will do one. the other is similar

Answer (score 1):

Assume $p$ and $q$ don't have common factors, i.e. p/q is reduced and $q \neq 1$, the same for $r$ and $s$.

Substitute and solve for $r^2$ to get
$$r^2={{\left(c\,q^3+b\,p\,q^2+a\,p^2\,q+p^3\right)\,s^2}\over{q^3}}$$

Now if $q$ divides $\left(c\,q^3+b\,p\,q^2+a\,p^2\,q+p^3\right)$ then it has to divide $p^3$ which is not possible. So $q^3$ divides $s^2$

Now solve for $c$ in the equation to get

$$\left[ c=-{{b\,p\,q^2\,s^2+a\,p^2\,q\,s^2+p^3\,s^2-q^3\,r^2}\over{q
 ^3\,s^2}} \right] $$
So $s^2$ should divide $q^3 r^2$. Since $r/s$ is reduced, $s^2$ divides $q^3$.

So
$$s^2 = q^3$$
So $q$ must have a square root, i.e. $q=t^2$. This gives $s=t^3$